# Uniquely identifying linux vms in azure WADMetric tables

Tags: azure, azure-diagnostics

We are developing software in c++ to retrieve linux network information from the azure WADMetrics tables.  We currently are using the Azure rest apis for this.

However the problem we have is a WADMetric table can contain data for multiple vms, and we currently only know about the Host value.  This maps to the host name in the guest, and it's possible that it's not unique.

The deploymentid in the tables does look like it uniquely identifies the machine, but there doesn't seem to be a way to get this via REST api.

Is there any way to identify a virtual machines data if the Host value is duplicated across machines?

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: Can you share the sample values you are seeing the PartitionKey / RowKey? The partition key should encode the ARM resource id of the VM

Comment: This is a sample PartitionKey. 

`002Fsubscriptions:002F<subscriptionid>:002FresourceGroups:002F<resourcegroupname>:002Fproviders:002FMicrosoft:002ECompute:002FvirtualMachines:002F<vmname>`

A sample row key

`2519106914399999999__:005CMemory:
005CAvailableMemory`

So it looks like there is data in the PartitionKey that might be of use.

Answer (score 2):

The deployment id is not present in these tables.

All Azure resources are identified by their Azure Resource Manager (ARM) resource id.  This value comes from user input in the Windows Azure Diagnostics (WAD) or Linux Diagnostic Extension (LDE) VM extension configuration.  You can see this value if you perform a GET on the https://management.azure.com/{resourceId}

The PartitionKey is set to the encoded ARM resource id of the VM.

PartitionKey = EscapeKey ( ARM resource id)

```
private static string EscapeStorageCharacter(char character)
{

    var ordinalValue = (ushort)character;
    if (ordinalValue < 0x100)
    {
        return string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, ":{0:X2}", ordinalValue);
    }
    else
    {
        return string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "::{0:X4}", ordinalValue);
    }
}

public static string EscapeKey(string storageKey)
{
    StringBuilder escapedStorageKey = new StringBuilder(storageKey.Length);
    foreach (char c in storageKey)
    {
        if (!char.IsLetterOrDigit(c))
        {
            escapedStorageKey.Append(EscapeStorageCharacter(c));
        }
        else
        {
            escapedStorageKey.Append(c);
        }
    }
 
    return escapedStorageKey.ToString();
}
```

Wrt RowKey, each metric value is written twice for two different indexes :

1) [EncodedMetricName]__[UTCTicks_DescendingOrder]

2) [UTCTicks_DescendingOrder]__[EncodedMetricName]

where UTCTicks_DescendingOrder is DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks - DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks padded to 19 digits.

If you are trying to read back all metric data by time, you should use index #2.

Comment: I actually do see a deploymentid in these tables, and the only place I see them is only in the tables.  They don't appear to be anyplace else.   

For the PartitionKey value do you know of any documentation on what the encoding is?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not aware of any external documentation for this but I updated the answer with a codesnippet

Comment: This is a pretty old post.  If you are trying to collect guest metrics, my recommendation is to send them as custom metrics to Azure Monitor and then you will be able to query the metrics directly from Azure Monitor Metrics REST API.  There are a lot of limitations with putting metrics into Azure table storage and custom metrics does not have any dependency on table storage  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/metrics-custom-overview